# Display html table with looping rmarkown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm encounting difficulties with some html tables display with mardown. I've coded an app with shiny which is supposed to compute some statistics and descriptive statistics with the package "table1".

Table1 allows me to get full descriptive statistics in html format. These tables are export to html file through the app and convert to pdf with chrome. Indeed, some tables are to large and are cut when the pdf transformation is done. So I've tried to split the tables by grouping them on factor variables.

Here's a minimal reproductible example :

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE}

library(table1)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
library(knitr)
var <- levels(iris$Species)

vect_table <- vector()

for (i in var) {

  df <- iris %>% filter(Species == i )

  tb <- table1(~., data = df)

  vect_table <- append(vect_table, tb)


}

for (j in 1: length(vect_table)) {

  print(kable(vect_table[j]), caption = paste("Specie : ",var[j] ))



}

```
````

The problem is, that I've no table displayed in the output (html), only the html code. I'm looking for any solutions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with `table1` but how about this:

````
```{r iris, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
library(table1)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
library(knitr)

results <- character()
iris_split <- split(iris, levels(iris$Species))
for (i in 1:length(iris_split)) {


  tb <- table1(~., data = iris_split[[i]])

  results <- c(results, "Specie : ", names(iris_split)[i], tb)
}

asis_output(results)
```
````